# tools suggestion for scheduling and caching

Tags: caching, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

We have a requirement to create a batch job for invoking web services and store the data in a caching mechanism. The batch job should execute in a regular manner in between some intervals. We are planning to schedule the service invocation and store the response in a caching mechanism. When I Google, I got quartz-scheduler  (http://quartz-scheduler.org/) for scheduling the job and ehcache (http://ehcache.org/) caching the response. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Any other tools for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

One of our customers uses ActiveBatch for scheduling: http://www.activebatch.com/home/products/default.aspx